# Dynamic SQL gives "Incorrect Syntax Near '+'"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am probably being extremely dumb here but why does this simple dynamic query:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT Id FROM dbo.Widgets WHERE Id = ' + 1;
```

Give `"Incorrect syntax near '+'"`

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't formulate the expression as part of the argument. And you shouldn't be concatenating that way anyway (think SQL injection) - you're using `sp_executesql` already, why not use a proper parameter?

```
DECLARE @Id INT, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Id = 1; -- presumably this will come from elsewhere

SET @sql = N'SELECT Id FROM dbo.Widgets WHERE Id = @Id;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Id INT', @Id;
```